# How can I recover a project after Remove from Recent Projects in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

So I was getting things mixed up between git clone and git pull.

And I thought I had pushed my recent changes to a remote GitHub repo, but I didn't.

And thinking I had pushed it, in the Pycharm start windows, I clicked on my project and clicked on 'Remove from Recent Projects'.

Now I am trying to get the project back - is this possible?

Get the project back.

Answer (score 0):

"Remove from Recent Projects" only removes the *shortcut* to the project in the Recent Projects menu. It does not delete the project.

You can still open the project by navigating to it in the "File" > "Open" dialog.

Comment: I had hope for a moment but I think it is lost. 

So where can I find the project?

Comment: FOund it!!! You are a life saver!

Comment: Days worth of work.... 

I found a directory called pycharm projects and found it there